# How Do you Transform Long Format Data, Where The Values Of One Column Are Now The New Column Names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I think this should be a relatively simple question, but I'm a bit stumped. I want to transform a pandas dataframe with two columns that looks like this:

`df`

```
Animal     rate
cat        .35
cat        .55
cat        .29
...
dog        .06
dog        .24
dog        .22
...
gecko      .47
gecko      .83
gecko      .42
...
```

Into this:

`df2`

```
cat   dog  gecko
.35  .06   .47
.55  .24   .83
.29  .22   .42
```

Each unique value in the Animal column of the original datafarme becomes the column heading of a new column, and its corresponding rates are beneath it. And that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a `cumcount` after `groupby` then `pivot`

```
out = df.assign(key=df.groupby('Animal').cumcount()).pivot('key','Animal','rate')
Out[29]: 
Animal   cat   dog  gecko
key                      
0       0.35  0.06   0.47
1       0.55  0.24   0.83
2       0.29  0.22   0.42
```